# psycopg2 type caster is created and registered but not found

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm trying to simply use floats instead of Decimals in psycopg2 as explained in the [FAQ](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/faq.html#faq-float). I am unable to get psycopg2 to use the custom type caster.

```
import psycopg2

psycopg2.extensions.DECIMAL.values   # Out: (1700,)
psycopg2.extensions.string_types[1700]   # Out: <psycopg2._psycopg.type 'DECIMAL' at 0x1104842c8>
```

There is the old type caster. Let's create a new one:

```
# Directly from documentation
DEC2FLOAT = psycopg2.extensions.new_type(
    psycopg2.extensions.DECIMAL.values,
    'DEC2FLOAT',
    lambda value, curs: float(value) if value is not None else None)
psycopg2.extensions.register_type(DEC2FLOAT)

psycopg2.extensions.string_types[1700]   # Out: <psycopg2._psycopg.type 'DEC2FLOAT' at 0x110435d18>
```

Ok, the new one is in dict of type casters. Let's try to use it:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname='test')
cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute('SELECT NULL::DEC2FLOAT')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ProgrammingError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-04a1f82b3b07> in <module>()
----> 1 cur.execute('SELECT NULL::DEC2FLOAT')

ProgrammingError: type "dec2float" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT NULL::DEC2FLOAT
                     ^
```

It's not found. So let's see if the old DECIMAL type caster is still there:

```
conn.rollback()
cur.execute('SELECT NULL::DECIMAL') # original caster works still...

psycopg2.extensions.string_types[1700]   # Out: [<psycopg2._psycopg.type 'DEC2FLOAT' at 0x110435d18>
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, especially since it's basically from the [docs](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/advanced.html#type-casting-from-sql-to-python). I've tried changing the scope of the register_type call. I've tried matching the case of the type caster name. I've tried re-ordering the register_type call and conn/cursor creation calls. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have registered an adapter, not a new type in Postgres. The adapter automatically converts `decimal` to `float`. Try this:

```
cur.execute("select 1.23")
row = cur.fetchone()
print(row[0], type(row[0]))

# output: 1.23 <class 'decimal.Decimal'>

DEC2FLOAT = psycopg2.extensions.new_type(
    psycopg2.extensions.DECIMAL.values,
    'DEC2FLOAT',
    lambda value, curs: float(value) if value is not None else None)
psycopg2.extensions.register_type(DEC2FLOAT)

cur.execute("select 1.23")
row = cur.fetchone()
print(row[0], type(row[0]))

# output: 1.23 <class 'float'>
```

Comment: Thank you! I was conflating the adapter and type caster concepts. I think the origin of my confusion was the last code snippet [here](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/advanced.html#type-casting-of-sql-types-into-python-objects) where they cast with the same name as their new adapter (i.e. `::point`). But it seems obvious now...